# Can I determine the limit of these functions by inserting?

Tags: limits, analysis, functions

Given:

1. $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{ex+3}{x+e}\right)^{(x^2-1)/(2x^2+6x+4)},$$
2. $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1-}(1-x)^{1-x^2}.$$

My ideas would be:

1. it holds that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{ex+3}{x+e} \right) = e$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{x^2-1}{2x^2+6x+4} \right) = \frac 1 2$, thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{ex+3}{x+e}\right)^{(x^2-1)/(2x^2+6x+4)} = e^{\frac 1 2} = \sqrt e$;
2. it holds that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1-} (1-x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1-} (1-x^2)=0$, thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1-}(1-x)^{1-x^2} = 0^0=:1$ (we have defined it that way).

The results are right, but is the approach right? Can you just look at the partial functions and derive the limit that way? If not, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ defined on $]0,\infty[\times \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, therefore (1) is fine.

There is no continuous function $f:(]0,\infty[\times ]0,\infty[)\cup\{(0,0)\}\to [0,\infty]$ such that  $f(x,y)=x^y$ for all $(x,y)\in ]0,\infty[\times ]0,\infty[$, therefore (2) is not fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, yes because
$$\left(\frac{ex+3}{x+e}\right)^{(x^2-1)/(2x^2+6x+4)}=e^{\log\left(\frac{ex+3}{x+e}\right)(x^2-1)/(2x^2+6x+4)} $$
so we're just using the continuity of $e^t$ and $\log(t)$.

For the second one, no because $0^0$ is an indeterminate form which means that the limit could potentially be equal to anything. For example, $\lim_{x\to0^+}0^x=0$ and it's of the form $0^0$. To solve it, take $t=1-x\to0^+$ as $x\to1^-$, and the limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^{2t-t^2}=e^{\lim_{t\to 0^+}{\log(t)t(2-t)}}$$
and use that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\log(t)=0$.

So the answer is you can plug in as long as we don't have an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution to 1) is correct but the solution to 2) is wrong, even though your answer is correct.

$(1-x)^{1-x^{2}}=e^{(1-x^{2}) \ln (1-x)}$ and $(1-x^{2}) \ln (1-x) \to 0$ as $x \to 1_{-}$ since $\lim_{t\to 0_{+}} tln t=0$. Hence the limit is $e^{0}=1$.